# How to get my ID on ARRAY from model on controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, elasticsearch

I have a case, this case really confuses me, because I try many solutions but I still didn't get my ID from my model.

Here is my case :

1. On my model I collect some data from database
2. then I pass it to my controller
3. of course this data will be an array ( am i right ? )
4. then on my controller, I only want to get my ID for another purpose (I will pass it again to my model, only my ID)
5. but I have become confused as for how to extract my data on controller

here follows my method to get an ID using my `$data['query']` :

```
$data['query']   = $this->mkomentar->get_all_($params);

$id = $data['query'];
$id_new = $id->hits->hits->_source->id;
```

and here follows my `var_dump $id_new` :

[image]

and here follows my `var_dump` for `$data['query']` :

```
object(stdClass)#17 (4) { ["took"]=> int(4) ["timed_out"]=> bool(false) ["_shards"]=> object(stdClass)#18 (3) { ["total"]=> int(5) ["successful"]=> int(5) ["failed"]=> int(0) } ["hits"]=> object(stdClass)#19 (3) { ["total"]=> int(1) ["max_score"]=> float(1.6931472) ["hits"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#20 (5) { ["_index"]=> string(11) "tryelastic2" ["_type"]=> string(11) "tryelastic2" ["_id"]=> string(20) "AVz4fiU3Gx0i_9jPP49l" ["_score"]=> float(1.6931472) ["_source"]=> object(stdClass)#21 (6) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["nama"]=> string(7) "Jhordan" ["url"]=> string(11) "jhordan.com" ["pesan"]=> string(5) "aiueo" ["code"]=> string(3) "247" ["status"]=> int(2) } } } } }
```

Comment: Update your question with your code not images of your code. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: ok, im sorry, already fix it @wolfgang1983

Comment: Also update question with your model function is this, Also What is `$id->hits->hits->_source->id;` a library function or another model function?

Comment: my code on model is function for query elasticsearch sir @wolfgang1983

Comment: add your model code with query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your controller code by replacing this and check whether your getting id 
and you can pass this id to model from controller

```
 $data['query']   = $this->mkomentar->get_all_($params);
foreach( $data['query'] as $loop) {
                 $id=$loop->id;//the id after loop-> is the column name in database
                 echo $id; //check whether id is getting
             }
```

Comment: oke, thank you @reshma , your answer help to solved my problem. ^^,